# Reading a text file and exporting its contents to sql

Tags: c#, sql, export, text-files, manifold

I'm trying to have files(.shp and image file types) that are listed(the location) in a text file exported to a database, by importing it into the manifold program and then exporting them from there into sql. The code is in C# and any references, similar coding and examples are welcomed.

info: I'm using Manifold System 8.0 Ultimate Edition(ver 8.0.15.0) and MS SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand you problem correctly, but how many shapefiles do you have? How about importing each one of them manually and then export them til SQL Server? There's a guide here on how to export to different databases.. http://www.manifold.net/doc/example_storing_a_drawing_in_manifold_spatial_dbms.htm

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been answered on the Manifold community forum:

http://forum.manifold.net/forum/t90256.3